# ACCESS SQL Adding Multiple Columns If They Don't Exist

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to add several new columns to a table that already exists in Access 2007 or 2010 with a query. Right now my code looks like this (yes, I'm terribly new to this):

ALTER TABLE AC_PROPERTY

ADD JAB_1 double,

JAB_2 double,

JAB_3 double;

This correctly adds the three columns when none of them already exist, but if any of them exist I get an error message and the query fails to run. I need it to add each columns only if it does not exist. Can anyone please help with what my code should look like to check if each column exists before trying to add it?

NOTE: I would just do 3 queries for each column, but I actually need to add 20+ columns. This is just a simple example of my actual use.

Thanks a billion!

Comment: Run three queries - each adding one field. That way, if one exists, it will still try to add the next two. If you want vba code to check if they exist, let me know.

Comment: This is just a simple example of my actual use. I need to add 20+ columns if they don't exist. The VBA code would really help. I have no idea how to use that but I can modify a working example! Thanks so much! @WayneG.Dunn

Answer (score 0):

Here is some old code.... it would be better to just check all fields in the same subroutine rather than opening/closing the DB, TDF, etc.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Function Check_If_Exists()
Dim strStatus   As String
    ' Add calls for the fields you want to append
    strStatus = Add_Field("MyFLd2", "Double")
    If strStatus = "Exists" Then
        Debug.Print "field present"
    ElseIf strStatus = "Added" Then
        Debug.Print "field added"
    End If
End Function

Function Add_Field(strFN, strType) As String

Dim db  As DAO.Database
Dim td  As DAO.TableDef
Dim fd  As DAO.Field
Dim strSQL  As String

    On Error GoTo Error_Trap
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set td = db.TableDefs("Table1")


'        ' List all field names
'        For Each fd In td.Fields
'            Debug.Print fd.Name
'        Next fd

    If IsNull(td.Fields(strFN)) Then
        Add_Field = "Exists"
    End If

    Set fd = Nothing
    Set td = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Function
Error_Trap:
    Debug.Print Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description
    If Err.Number = 3265 Then
        Add_Field = "Added"
        strSQL = "alter table Table1 ADD " & strFN & " " & strType & ";"
        db.Execute strSQL
        db.TableDefs.Refresh
    End If
    Exit Function
    Resume
End Function
```